# Passing a variable number of arguments to a Redis Lua script

Tags: redis, lua

I am using `EVAL` to pass several arguments to my Lua script. However, the last argument is optional, it may or it may be not passed to `EVAL`.

How can I check in a Redis Lua script whether an argument is there or not? For example, if `ARGV[3]` exists or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ARGV[3] then
    -- user pass in ARGV[3]
else
    -- No ARGV[3]
end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    redis.call('DEL', KEYS[1])
    local members = {}
    for i = 0, tonumber(ARGV[1]), 1 do
        members[i] = ARGV[1+i]
    end
    redis.call('SADD', KEYS[1], unpack(members))
    return 1
```